# Do mechanically recycled plastics decompose more rapidly?

Tags: plastics, decomposition

Does it mean that mechanically recycled plastics decompose more rapidly in the environment? So even if mechanical recycling doesn't prevent plastics from going to landfills, just puts it off (incinerators aside), it ameliorates the situation by making them go away faster, doesn't it?

> The authors suggest that the susceptibility of a polymer to shear-induced degradation is directly proportional to its chain length and degree of chain branching,  a  phenomenon confirmed by  Gooenie et al. and La Mantia et al. for PET. Thus, the length of polymer chain controls degradation kinetics (suggesting that it can autoaccelerate through repeated extrusion)  whereas thermo-oxidative processes are dictated by the both structure of and oxygen diffusion through the polymer matrix. Environmental oxygen reacts with shear-induced radicals and subsequent reactions produce peroxy radicals which propagate radical decomposition. Thus,  high oxygen permeability leads to increased thermo-oxidation rates within the material.

*(from [here](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/marc.202000415))*

Comment: Well, it would be very weird if opposite happened. Microplastics are still a problem, though.

Comment: @Mithoron Did I interpret that passage right, or did I overinterpret?